# Scrape data from google image search results

Tags: php, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I have to scrape data from google.

For example, this URL:

```
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=https://traum-deutung.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/traumdeutung-offener-sarg-symbol-768x768.jpg
```

but when I scrape it and echo the data variable, it simply shows me the google page like this:

[image: this is the image after scraping]

This is actual result from google image search but I didn't find its code in my php script:

[image: this is actual result from google image search but I didn't find its code in my php script]

> **the code i use for this**

```
 <?php
  require 'simple_html_dom.php';
  $link = $_GET['link'];
  if (!isset($link) || empty($link)) {
    echo "please provide a link". "<br> \n";
    echo "EXAMPLE : <br>";
    echo "example.com?link=HERE PUT IMAGE LINK";
    die();

    }

    $html = file_get_html('https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url='. $link);
    echo $html;
 ?>
```

Comment: We are still missing your coding attempt

Comment: have you even looked at the source code for Google Images results page?

Comment: yes i looked the source code it's showing some js function no HTML...